# Getting error next is not a function in node js / express js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am getting this error:

> next is not a function

when I write `next();` in my controller but can't figure out why is the error coming even though I defined it in the function params.

Router Js:

```js
router.post('/era', controlleri.book, booking_controller.book, function (req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('okay');
  console.log("done in server.js");
});
```

This is my router file in which I want to carry out function synchronously so thats why I am using `next();`.

Controller.Book function code:

```
module.exports.book = function (req,res,next) {
  var dates = req.body.dates;
  var times = req.body.times;
  var result = "yes";

  var query=`dates.${dates}.${times}.ava`;

  db.mohd.find({ [query]:result }, { userid: 1, _id: 0 }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(404);
    } else if (docs == null) {
      res.send(404);   
    } else {
      if (req.body) {
        var thid=req.body.therapist_id;
        var dates=req.body.dates;
        var times=req.body.times;
        var query=`dates.${dates}.${times}.ava`;

        db.mohd.update(
          { userid: thid },
          { $set: { [query]: "no" } }, 
          function () {
            console.log("updated");
          }
        );
                       
        // Here the error occurs
        next();
      } else {
        res.send("Get the F out of here");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Although the next function i.e `booking_controller.book` is executed but the program stops by giving the error:

```
next is not a function
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code. This is just a chaos.

Comment: I can't see `next` defined in your function params. Could you provode us a with a bit more code please?

Comment: Sorry added Full proper code @Pedro

Comment: try to move `if(req.body){ ... else` to outside `else`

Comment: Wait this is old; why did it show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass next as the 3rd parameter of the find callback function.

> function(err, docs, next) { ... }

Comment: Why? Even assuming the DB callback took an Express-related callback function *(which would be Really Weird)* `next` is in the callback functions' closures.